# Minimum time quantum needed in nanosleep(), usleep() to yield the CPU

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, concurrency, kernel

In concurrent code in my workplace, there are several occurrences of nanosleep() or usleep() with a *non-zero constant* to free up the CPU without relying on futex(), or a sleeping synchronization primitive to put the thread to sleep (for instance, when waiting for an element from a concurrent queue). The code claims to prevent pathological cases where threads consume CPU without doing any actual work when other threads are available to get scheduled on that CPU. This sounds reasonable by itself assuming the cooperation between the sleep functions and the kernel thread scheduler is correct.

Is there a concept in linux where a minimum duration passed to nanosleep(), usleep(), et al. is known to put the calling thread to sleep and run another thread in it's place on the same core when cores are oversubscribed? And if the duration is smaller than that, then the thread does not actually yield the CPU but continue spinning? This forms the basis of the constant passed to the sleep() functions in order to make it behave like a coarse-yield.

---

I realize that a sched_yield() is probably better suited for what the code is doing; but I just wanted to educate myself on the behavior of the linux sleep() functions before benchmarking a replacement or improvement on the existing code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The man page makes it clear that it no longer busy-waits.

> In order to support applications requiring much more precise pauses
>   (e.g., in order to control some time-critical hardware), nanosleep()
>   would handle pauses of up to 2 milliseconds by busy waiting with
>   microsecond precision when called from a thread scheduled under a
>   real-time policy like SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR.  This special extension
>   was removed in kernel 2.5.39, and is thus not available in Linux
>   2.6.0 and later kernels.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not fully sure what that means - it's saying that the busy wait no longer happens, does this mean that the sleep functions always yield the CPU if there is another ready thread without taking into consideration how long the sleep duration was?

Comment: Yes.   Now it always yields.  If there is no other waiting thread, then it will run the system's idle task.

Comment: Thanks! That answers my question completely. Just for my sanity, do you know of some source that I can use to prove this behavior to other people?

Answer (score 1):

@stark has answered your question as written, but to elaborate, **don't do that**. If you're waiting for an event to happen, perform an operation that waits for the event, like `pthread_cond_wait`, `sem_wait`, `poll`, `read`, etc. rather than sleeping and retrying. This will avoid wasting lots of cpu time, and it also discourages erroneous programming models full of data races (because normally the same primitive that waits also ensures exclusive access/synchronization).